# What's the opposite word for "Host"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms, antonyms

Not really opposite word but more like a corresponding word?

> Teacher - Student
>
> Doctor - Patient
>
> Interviewer - Interviewee
>
> Host - ??? (Guest? Hostee?)

I cannot find anything that feels right. ***Host*** here refers to a host in a *group meeting or a coffee chat*.

Answer (score 5):

***Guest*** is the right corresponding term and this is what I would personally use. It is commonly used in a variety of situations:

> a person who is staying with you, or *a person you have invited to a social occasion*, *such as a party or a meal* ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/guest))

*Guest* is very used on sites to differentiate between ***members*** who have an account and *(anonymous) **guests*** or ***guest users*** who do not have an account, or have a different type of account. So *guest* would go well in the *chat* situation as well.

But there is also the slightly more technical term
***invitee***:

> a person who is invited to something:
>
> - an *invitee* to the White House ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/invitee))

This one is more formal, but it might express better what you need, as it focuses more on the fact of *being invited*.

In law, *invitees* and *licensees* are both ***guests***, but:

> The main difference between an *invitee* and *licensee* is that ***an invitee has been invited for business purposes*** while a ***licensee is someone there for social purposes or a reason unrelated to business***. ([burkelaw](https://www.sburkelaw.com/faqs/what-is-the-difference-between-an-invitee-and-licensee-.cfm))

Comment: In a meeting scenario, an invitee becomes an attendee when they join.

Comment: Yes, true. But the _attendee_ has less of the _being invited_ connotation, which is what creates the relationship between host and guests: the one who invites and the ones who are invited. (Like in the teacher-student relationship, the one who teaches and the one who is taught). Giver-receiver.

Comment: "Guest" is the obvious choice. There are more specific words for different roles people might have at a meeting (e.g. observer, facilitator, chair, visitor, secretary, clerk...) and it's not always clear who the host is (one person may book the room, another invite everyone, someone else chair the meeting, someone else might be the higher-up in the organisation, etc), but absent those considerations "guest" works.

Comment: _Attendee_ is a wastebasket word. If you can't call'em something polite, call'em attendees; they attended, didn't they? No more needs to be said, and soon they'll be gone.